# Seconds_Behind_Master crece constantemente en servidor Slave de MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo configurado un servidor esclavo corriendo sobre Debian 9 en MariaDB 10.1. Lo configuré y puse a funcionar y todo bien, lo que me preocupa es que cada ves se retrasa más la variable Seconds_Behind_Maste. Empezó con 1 segundo de retraso y ya va por 16 y cada vez se retrasa más. Esta es la lectura consecutiva del log, como verán cada vez se retrasa más. Alguien me puede ayudar ? Saludos..

1. LECTURA 1.

```
    show slave status\G
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
                   Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                      Master_Host: oculto por seguridad
                      Master_User: oculto por seguridad
                      Master_Port: 3306
                    Connect_Retry: 60
                  Master_Log_File: log-bin.005272
              Read_Master_Log_Pos: 135257692
                   Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000008
                    Relay_Log_Pos: 57338823
            Relay_Master_Log_File: log-bin.005270
                 Slave_IO_Running: Yes
                Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
                  Replicate_Do_DB: BdProduccion1
              Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
               Replicate_Do_Table: 
           Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
          Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                       Last_Errno: 0
                       Last_Error: 
                     Skip_Counter: 0
              Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 415674922
                  Relay_Log_Space: 850673341
                  Until_Condition: None
                   Until_Log_File: 
                    Until_Log_Pos: 0
               Master_SSL_Allowed: No
               Master_SSL_CA_File: 
               Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
                  Master_SSL_Cert: 
                Master_SSL_Cipher: 
                   Master_SSL_Key: 
            **Seconds_Behind_Master: 16912**
    Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                    Last_IO_Errno: 0
                    Last_IO_Error: 
                   Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                   Last_SQL_Error: 
      Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
                 Master_Server_Id: 50
                   Master_SSL_Crl: 
               Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                       Using_Gtid: No
                      Gtid_IO_Pos: 
          Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
      Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                    Parallel_Mode: conservative
                        SQL_Delay: 0
              SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
          Slave_SQL_Running_State: Unlocking tables
```

En la segunda lectura ya iba por Seconds_Behind_Master: 187234, alguien puede ayudarme y decirme que pasa con esto ?

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por la respuesta. El problema es que el disco del slave es HDD y el Master es SSD por lo que la escritura en uno es muy superior al otro. Seteando innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 resolví el problema.

Controls the balance between strict ACID compliance for commit operations and higher performance that is possible when commit-related I/O operations are rearranged and done in batches. You can achieve better performance by changing the default value but then you can lose transactions in a crash.

The default setting of 1 is required for full ACID compliance. Logs are written and flushed to disk at each transaction commit.

With a setting of 0, logs are written and flushed to disk once per second. Transactions for which logs have not been flushed can be lost in a crash.

With a setting of 2, logs are written after each transaction commit and flushed to disk once per second. Transactions for which logs have not been flushed can be lost in a crash.

For settings 0 and 2, once-per-second flushing is not 100% guaranteed. Flushing may occur more frequently due to DDL changes and other internal InnoDB activities that cause logs to be flushed independently of the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit setting, and sometimes less frequently due to scheduling issues. If logs are flushed once per second, up to one second of transactions can be lost in a crash. If logs are flushed more or less frequently than once per second, the amount of transactions that can be lost varies accordingly.

DDL changes and other internal InnoDB activities flush the log independently of the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit setting.

InnoDB crash recovery works regardless of the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit setting. Transactions are either applied entirely or erased entirely.

For the greatest possible durability and consistency in a replication setup using InnoDB with transactions, use innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 and sync_binlog=1 in your master server my.cnf file.
[innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit)
Otro detalle. En ocasiones la latencia se produce por la velocidad del enlace y otros temas referentes a la red. En este caso pruebe setear:
slave_compressed_protocol = 1 en my.cnf
Description: If set to 1 (0 is the default), will use compression for the slave/master protocol if both master and slave support this.
Commandline: --slave-compressed-protocol
Scope: Global
Dynamic: Yes
Data Type: boolean
Default Value: 0
[slave_compressed_protocol](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#slave_compressed_protocol)

Comment: Podrías traducirlo al castellano para que otras personas de la comunidad puedan entenderlo a pesar que no sepan Ingles? seguro muchos te lo agradecerían.

Comment: Cambiar innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 en Slaves es lo habitual, nunca hacerlo en un Master o en Slaves que puedan ser promocionados a Master. Ya que no se garantiza la recuperación de datos a la hora de que MySQL falle y entre en modo recuperación.

Answer (score 0):

Nos indica que hay retraso en el Slave y no está al día, el valor indica la cantidad de segundos que está retrasado y este termino le decimos **lag**, lo ideal es que siempre esté en 0, si empieza a incrementar éste número puede ser por los siguientes motivos:

1. El hardware del Slave es inferior al Master y no es capaz de procesar todo el trafico entrante. Se recomienda que el Master y el Slave tengan en principio el mismo hardware y luego puedes ir ajustándolo. Revisa los siguientes sub-puntos:

   1.1. El disco no debe estar saturado **IOPS**, puedes usar esta herramienta de percona [pt-diskstats](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-diskstats.html) para averiguarlo.

   1.2. Asegurate que el Slave no tenga la **CPU** saturada.

   1.3. Asegurate que el Slave solo este haciendo su trabajo de Slave y no **hayan otros servicios** ejecutándose y que le resten recursos.
2. Hay un proceso que esta bloqueando alguna tabla, por ejemplo:

   2.1. **Consultas lentas** que pueden estar bloqueando la tabla, puedes usar el `slow_log` para identificarlas. Para ver las tablas bloqueadas puedes usar `SHOW OPEN TABLES`.

   2.2. Puede ser que estes haciendo un **ALTER TABLE** o usando una herramienta [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html)
3. Puede que haya más actividad de **escritura adicional** como un General Log, o un BinLog activado, puede que no sea necesario.
4. Puede que tengas mucha actividad de escritura en el Master y el Slave no puede procesarlo a tiempo, esto puede ser por un proceso periódico que este controlado. Al ser este el caso te recomiendo hacer `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` por bloques controlados y con espacios de tiempo entre ellos, por ejemplo: `INSERT` de 100 en 100 y con un tiempo de espera de 1 segundo.

Una ves que sepas donde esta el cuello de botella que genera el lag, podremos saber si debemos incrementar los recursos del hardware, agregar indices, refactorizar alguna parte del código de la aplicación o cambiar alguna variable de configuración de la base de datos.